# What problems will I face if I buy an imported Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-network

I am thinking about buying an Xbox One from eBay from US to Ghana for my birthday. It comes with a download code for Assassin's Creed: Unity. Before I buy it these are the questions I have,

1. Ghana does not support Xbox Live, so what should I do? I heard people say that you have to change the console location to US and also have a VPN with US address, then put a US based Xbox live profile. Is that true? Is it possible to play multiplayer using Gold if this problem is solvable?
2. Will I face any restrictions from redeeming the game code? I heard that digital copy isn't region free. And what should I do to prevent this? The console is NTSC version (American version)
3. Will I face restrictions when I digitally download games from Microsoft Store? Is there a safe way to go around it.
4. Should I take a PAL version of XBOX ONE

Lastly, with all these problems, do you reckon I should stick with the Xbox One or leave it for good and go for PS4.  And the console is NTSC version

Comment: As far as I know the XB1 is entirely region free. You can even change your console's region at any time and play the localized game for that region (if it has one). I'm not certain how payments and digital purchases will work, but I do know that disc games will work.

Answer (score 1):

The Xbox One is region-free but only for physical copies of games. If you want to purchase content online then you need to have a US bank account, as Ghana is not a supported country. I have an Xbox One S - NTSC and I redeemed the Minecraft code that I got. I can assure you that there will be no problem faced while redeeming the code.